# jQuery. How to optimize replace src

Tags: jquery, query-optimization

Please help me to optimize this code, because it works very slow.

```
$("img[src*='bt_']").each(function() {
 var newSrc = $(this).attr('src');
 var violetCheck = "/violet/";
if(newSrc.indexOf(violetCheck) == -1){
    newSrc = newSrc.replace('images/','images/violet/');
    $(this).attr('src', newSrc);
  } 
});
```

Comment: what are you trying to do with it?

Comment: Post the html element(s) you are trying to proccess.

Comment: It looks like you can't really avoid a linear complexity here if you need to loop through every img.

Comment: I want to find all icons with bt_prefix, read  their src attr and replace part of this path.

Comment: Is there no way you can do this server side with a variable containing the path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    $("img [src*='bt_']:not(src*='/violet/')").each(function() {
               var src = $(this).attr("src").replace('images/','images/violet/');
               $(this).attr("src", src);
     });
```

Answer (score 1):

`$("img[src*='bt_']")` will do a search over your whole document instead of replacing inside of a specific part of the document.

```
<body>
<div>data not containing img OR not targetted content</div>
<div id="targettedcontent">
<img src="bt_...........
</div>
</body>
```

and then use `$("#targettedcontent img[src*='bt_']")......`

This will surely improve performance.

Comment: In my situations buttons are placed on all page. Maby I sholud to use .filter?